# How to redirect any picture filetype to a php file of the same name?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, redirect, sharing

Im trying to build a Image sharing site(Mostly for fun).
so my current predicament is how to make any image i have redirect to a php file of the same name.

I.E

```
      www.example.com/folder/fuzzycat.jpg

      Should goto

      www.example.com/folder/fuzzycat.php
```

That way i can css and JS it to my heart's content.
i'm trying to do it with the **.htaccess** file so i'm not having to implement some framework or anything that would slow my site.

Thank You.

Comment: If you think that doing a script per image is a good solution to any problem including performance, I would strongly suggest you to find tutorials that will teach you the basics of programming.  Whatever the approach, there are always better ways to customize individual pages to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

In the `/folder/.htaccess`, you can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```